# How do I turn an array of bits in an bitstring where each bit represents one boolean in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, binary, pack

The question is pretty self explanatory. I want to turn something like `[true, true, false, true]` into the following bitstring 1101.

I assume I need to use Array.pack, but I can't figure out exactly how to do this.

Comment: is bitstring `"1001"` or `"\x01\x01\x00\x01"`?

Comment: Do you mean `[true,true,false,true].map { |t| t ? '1' : '0' }.join.to_i(2) #=>13`? That is, the string representation of  `13` in binary is `13.to_s(2) #=> "1101"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how exactly you want to represent the boolean Array.

For `[true, true, false, true]`, should it be `0b1101` or `0b11010000`? I assume it's the former, and you may get it like this:

```
data = [true, true, false, true]
out = data
  .each_slice(8) # group the data into segments of 8 bits, i.e., a byte
  .map {|slice|
    slice
      .map{|i| if i then 1 else 0 end } # convert to 1/0
      .join.to_i(2)                     # get the byte representation
  }
  .pack('C*')
p out #=> "\r"
```

PS. There may be further endian problem depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
ary = [true, true, false, true]

ary.map { |b| b ? 1.chr : 0.chr }.join
#=> "\x01\x01\x00\x01"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do this with pack

First turn your booleans into a string

```
bit_string = [true, false, false,true].map {|set| set ? 1 :0}.join
```

Pad the string with zeroes if needed

```
bit_string = "0" * (8 - (bit_string.length % 8)) + bit_string if bit_string.length % 8 != 0
```

Then pack

```
[bit_string].pack("B*")
```

Comment: Three points (but I must be careful as I seem to often misspeak when I comment on your answers): 1) `.join` (which I'm sure you had) is AWOL; 2) wouldn't the padding operation read better (though it might be ever-so-slightly less efficient) if you were to drop the unneeded `if` clause?; and 3) the padding could also be done as follows: `'1001'.rjust(8*(bit_string.size/8.0).ceil,'0') #=> "00001001"`. I have nothing to say about `pack` because thinking about it gives me a headache.

Comment: I nearly used ceil but thought that it was less obvious (if more concise). Good spot on join

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `to_i` method for `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`. Something like this:

```
class TrueClass
  def to_i
    1
  end
end
class FalseClass
  def to_i
    0
  end
end
[true, true, false, true].map(&:to_i).join
# => "1101"
```

Comment: I need to turn it into a bitstring instead of a string of integers - any idea how I'd do that?

Comment: there is no in-built class as such bitstring in Ruby. If you want an integer output you can use `to_i` at the end i.e. `[true, true, false, true].map(&:to_i).join.to_i`