# How do I turn arguments 'integer<120 boolean boolean boolean boolean' into the most compact package possible

Tags: arrays, ruby, pack

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554317/how-do-i-turn-an-array-of-bits-in-an-bitstring-where-each-bit-represents-one-boo) but considering the extra argument that's 60+ times the information, I've become confused.

I plan on writing a converter for end users that will take arguments,

```
$genmask int>5<120b[bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)]
```

and convert that to a mask that the script can then read, but what if I want them to be able to leave out an option and have it generate correctly.

currently, I'm trying things out like

```rb
120.to_s(36) + [1.to_s(36), 2.to_s(36), 4.to_s(36), 8.to_s(36)].join
# => "3c1248"
```

but that isn't quite what I'm looking for, I'm more so looking for the direct addition, like that of linux permissions or where the whole thing can be written in 1-3 characters.

I may be making it too complicated, I don't know.

Comment: Can you explain what `$genmask int>5<120b[bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)][bool(0,1)]` means?

Comment: @KeithBennett Sorry, it is a bot command, $ being the bot's prefix

so as it stands the command would be
`<MyNick> $genmask 20b1111`

20 for the length, and then 1 being true for the booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four Boolean arguments corresponds to a four-bit number, which can be represented as a single hexadecimal character. So if you think your users can do hexadecimal addition, you can use that.

```
flags = [true, true, true, true]
flags.map { |b| b ? 1 : 0 }.join.to_i(2).to_s(16)
# "f"

"5".to_i(16).to_s(2).rjust(4, ?0).each_char.map { |c| c == ?1 }
# [ false, true, false, true]
```

And since you can represent 120 in two characters with base 36, that gets all your arguments in 3 characters as desired.

But to be honest that sounds like an awfully confusing interface. chmod's octal arguments are *barely* understandable and this looks way more confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, and so right now it stands at just using

        `<MyNick> $genpass 20 1 1 1 1`